# Signed assembly seems to be loading unsigned (not using reflection)

Tags: .net, assemblies

I have three .NET 4.0 third party assemblies:

- `Assembly.One` is unsigned and references a signed `Assembly.Two` and unsigned `Assembly.Three`.
- `Assembly.Two` references a **signed** `Assembly.Three`.

I've verified the above using reflector.

I have been provided with an unsigned `Assembly.One`, signed `Assembly.Two` and **unsigned** `Assembly.Three`.

I expected this to fall over when deployed as the signed `Assembly.Two` surely cannot load the unsigned `Assembly.Three` given that it's specifically looking for the signed version from it's reference?  However, to my surprise it works.

`Assembly.Two` has the reference to `Assembly.Three` in it's manifest so it must be using it otherwise the compiler would have stripped it out?  I've checked there are no signed versions of `Assembly.Three` on the server and using FUSLOGVW it is indeed loading the unsigned version.

There are two entries in FUSLOGVW for the loading of unsigned `Assembly.Three` with the one for a calling assembly of (Unknown) showing the following.

> A partially-specified assembly bind succeeded from the application
>   directory. Need to re-apply policy

Could there be a potential "chain of responsibility" (for lack of a better description) that is allowing this that I'm not aware of since the originating `Assembly.One` has a reference to the unsigned `Assembly.Three`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any "Configured Assemblies" in app.config, Machine.Config etc performing redirection?  Or other configured settings to change the behaviour?

Check to make sure that "Specific Version = true" in the reference to the assembly. Are you referencing the Unsigned `Assembly.Three` in your project to force a "copy", but you don't actually use Three directly? Make sure that `Assembly.Two` is loaded before your Local reference to `Three` kicks in, or don't reference Three at all directly let `Two` make that decision.

Load info here [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from this information #2 may be what is happening for you.